# DynamoDB query in Java stopped working and returns empty collection

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a method that query DynamoDB for newest data that all of a sudden stopped working (returns empty collection instead of items that are in database). Also it seems that the value passed to `withKeyConditionExpression` is not validated anymore (I can pass any String and no error is thrown). What could be the reason of such behavior, what I'm missing?

My code:

```
private ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> getNewestData(String client, long lastTimestamp){
        Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
        expressionAttributeNames.put("#timestamp", "TIMESTAMP");
        QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("MY_ID = :my_id and #timestamp > :my_timestamp")
                .withNameMap(expressionAttributeNames)
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withString(":my_id", client)
                        .withNumber(":my_timestamp", lastTimestamp));

        return table.query(spec);
```

Comment: your code works fine for me. make sure that you have a table with hash key MY_ID and range key TIMESTAMP. your method `getNewestData()` will not throw exception (even if `withKeyConditionExpression ` is absolutely wrong)  until you try to iterate over ItemCollection result.

Comment: Your comment helped me track the bug! Later in code there was condition on `getAccumulatedItemCount()` that was inserted before iteration.